# Bug in Mono System.Net.Socket or I misunderstand something? (incorrect number of bytes sent returned)

Tags: c#, mono, network-programming

After playing a while with Mono, I see one strange thing - every call to Send(), EndSend(), SendAsync() etc return not number of bytes sent in this particular operation, but total number of bytes sent during the lifetime of a Socket.

According to various sources (including official Microsoft documentation), the number of bytes sent should reflect only last operation (which seems logical and standard), but in Mono this is different.

I've tried Mono 2.8.2, 2.10.5 - this behaviour is still there. Looking into sources (including master on GitHub), I see that this is "behaviour by design", however, this contradicts to documented behaviour.

So, my question is - is this a bug in Mono, or I misunderstood something? If this is a bug - how could it happen that it lurks there for years, and nobody noticed?

Comment: I'd say it's a bug. File a [bug report](http://www.mono-project.com/Bugs). "how could it happen" - many (if not all) people assume that the number of bytes sent equals the number of bytes passed to Send/BeginSend and don't bother checking the return value.

Comment: Do you have a link to the source for this?

Comment: A minimal working sample would greatly enhance my incentive to go and test it across runtime versions and platforms

Comment: Minimal working sample may be any code using Socket class and Send() method - monitoring its return value will demonstrate the problem.  The source of problem is here: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket_2_1.cs - look for usage of "send_so_far" starting at line 687 - value is not reset after each send.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but can't reproduce that with Send or EndSend. Considering test program and Mono's source code I would say there is no bug in Mono. Details below.

I used this code to test, it is not beautiful, however shows what should be shown:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace Test2
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {       
            var t = new Thread(Read) { IsBackground = true };
            t.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(300);
            var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1234));
            for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(socket.Send(new [] {(byte) 0x12}));
            }
        }

        public static void Read()
        {
            var s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            s.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1234));
            s.Listen(1);
            var accepted = s.Accept();
            while(true)
            {
                accepted.Receive(new byte[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On my machine output is:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Which is what expected. I was testing using Mono from git commit b21a860 on Ubuntu 10.10. About `send_so_far`, you mentioned: please notice, that call to `int Send (byte [] buf)` calls `internal int Send_nochecks(...)` and this in turn calls `int Send_internal (socket, buf, offset, size, flags, out nativeError)` which is tagged with `[MethodImplAttribute (MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]` (so implemented directly in runtime) and uses no `send_so_far` at all. (As far as I can see, `send_so_far` is used in AsyncResult, but only in one AsyncResult, therefore it does not have to be zeroed - you can't call EndSend twice on same AsyncResult.).

**EDIT:**

I have just tested it with async version (i.e. EndSend) and it works properly too. Could you post some piece of problematic code?

Comment: +1, I have performed similar tests when working on Sharp SNMP Suite, and never meet a problem like this.

Comment: OK, sorry guys - I did look into source very briefly and assumed that it affects all Send() operations. In fact, it does affect only SendAsync(). The source is here: http://codepaste.net/zjdm19 - on Mono  BytesTransferred is increasing from call to call, on .NET it is 1.

Comment: That's correct, I was able to reproduce described behaviour using `SendAsync()`. Good you've found that. About why nobody noticed this till this moment, I would say that SendAsync is quite rarely used mechanism. In most places I have seen people tend to use Send in blocking and BeginSend/EndSend in non-blocking operation (as I did in my first tests), which both work fine. I'll try to make a patch and submit pull request on that bug today or tomorrow.